# Processing many files in a folder parallely using python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a folder with 100 excel files. From my program I have to process all the files. I want to do this parallely using multithreading or multiprocessing using python. I am planning to use 10 threads or processes where each of them will process 10 files. the first thread/process should process files 1-10,second  11-20 files,likewise. I tried using multithreading in python but not sure how to index on specific file? Any suggestions will be most welcome

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do multiprocessing is as follows:

```
files = [ ... list of file names generated somehow ... ]

def process_file(file_name):
    .... process file named file_name however you want ...

with multiprocessing.Pool(10) as pool:
    pool.map(process_file, files, 10);
```

The 10 indicates you want 10 threads.  The second 10 indicates that you want to send the files to each thread in chunks of 10.  Variants of `map()` exist that can take care of many of your needs.

Comment: hi, so in this case i should read all the folder contents and keep it in a list structure right. if the number of files is very high is it possible to make each process or thread read from the folder directly

Comment: You haven't said anything about how you get your file names, or what sort of processing you're doing on them.  So my answers have to be very generic.  The second argument to pool.map can be any sort of list, sequence, or iterator.  It's up to you whether "file" is the name of a file, and process_file reads it, or if "file" is the already read contents, and process_file just extracts the data.  Whatever works best.

Comment: And changing `multiprocess.Pool` to `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` gives you a thread pool rather than a process pool.  All the setup and cleanup is taken care of for you.

Comment: In my case, i am thinking of reading all the files in a folder and storing it in a list structure.   pool.map ensures that the second process reads from files 11 to 20?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 has an inbuild library "threading". Here is an example:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import random

def slow_function(i):
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))
    print(i)

def running_threads():
    threads = []
    for i in range(10):
        t = Thread(target=slow_function, args=(i,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()  # making sure that all your threads are done before doing something else with all results

running_threads()
```